# Regarding msg_control ancilliary data from sys/socket.h

Tags: c, sockets

From https://linux.die.net/man/2/recvmsg:

> When recvmsg() is called, msg_controllen should contain the length of
>   the available buffer in msg_control; upon return from a successful
>   call it will contain the length of the control message sequence. The
>   messages are of the form:
>       struct cmsghdr {
>           socklen_t     cmsg_len;     /* data byte count, including hdr */
>           int           cmsg_level;   /* originating protocol */
>           int           cmsg_type;    /* protocol-specific type */
>       /* followed by
>           unsigned char cmsg_data[]; */
>       };

1) Given that msg_control is a pointer to the first byte, is 'the length of the control message sequence' the size in bytes of all the cmsghdr structs in the sequence put together, or the number of cmsghdr structs in the sequence?

2) Is it permissable to make a byte-for-byte copy of a msghdr struct (which contains all the cmsghdr structs) and have the relevant macros (like CMSG_FIRSTHDR()) access the copy as they would the original?